# An application-internal exception has occurred

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I tried running my Windows Phone 8.1 XAML App, but it does not get past this exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x75B20D83 (TWINAPI.APPCORE.DLL) in Neomilano.WindowsPhone.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x0300E460, 0x00000001).

I don't know what causes this. Maybe some of you do. I'll add details if needed.

Any help?

**UPDATE**: If it helps, [here's what's on the output window.](http://pastebin.com/HLvMFCjN)

Comment: More deatails would be a good idea here. When this exception is thrown? Have you tried to debug your App - set breakpoints at App.xaml.cs file?

Comment: It pops out on-load. Tried putting a breakpoint on the InitializeComponent method at App() at App.xaml.cs. That breakpoint is not catched. The debugger breaks first with the exception ending at that message posted above.

Comment: Are you running on Emulator or device? If device then few tries: check if you have the App with the same ID on the phone (beta test/normal version) (you may also try to change app id). Try to restart the phone, clean project build once more.

Comment: I'm running on a device. Restarted the phone, cleaned and rebuilt the solution. Doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to run any other App on the device?

Comment: Yep, I don't have any problems on other apps.

Comment: check [this](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=0dcffd79-3848-4cc3-839d-ab7d3544f80a)

Comment: This happened on my Windows 10 UWP app when I changed from using the managed only debugger to using the native only debugger. A clean and full rebuild appears to have resolved the problem.